# How to print Qt Hebrew QStrings to the console?

Tags: linux, qt, hebrew

On my arm-based device Hebrew QStrings are displayed as garbage ("???? ?????"), but with the correct number of '?' characters, when sent to the console with qDebug().
On my PC (Ubuntu 14.04) it's working fine.

**Interesting**: if I cat my_hebrew_file.txt - Hebrew is displayed correctly.

Comment: You need to set proper codec. Try `QTextCodec::codecForName("ISO8859-8")`.

Comment: Are you sure Hebrew language supported is installed on you device?

Answer (score 0):

1. `qDebug()`: [The format should be a Latin-1 string.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qDebug)
2. You may be able to override it with your [own message handler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler).